# Implementing a single sign on for a set of WCF services

Tags: wcf, single-sign-on

I'm developing a set of WCF services that theoretically can be used stand-alone, but in practice have some sort of a client that usually makes multiple calls over the services in a single session.

Our backend authentication mechanism is quite heavy and requires calls to another authentication provider service.

However, I would like to avoid the overhead of doing the authentication on every invocation of a service.

looking for patterns /architectural guidance around this.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

read following link 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/ad610761-e398-4d62-90de-53578636b002

[WCF - SSO authentication token and POX interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338380/wcf-sso-authentication-token-and-pox-interfaces)

http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2006/03/14/implementing-a-secure-token-service-with-wcf.aspx